# How to overwrite a previously uploaded malformed upstream tarball in Launchpad's PPA?

Tags: package-management, software-installation, ppa, packaging

I have been maintaining a PPA for quite a while for an open-source project. On the new release of the program, I compiled the `.deb` package accidentally with a malformed upstream tarball and uploaded it.

The build failed obviously, but then, I changed my upstream tarball to the right one but PPA is rejecting my upload with such message:

> File `<filename>` already exists in `<name>`, but uploaded version has different contents.

#### So my question is..

How do I overwrite that file? I just want to reupload with a different tarball. I bumped the version in the `debian/changelog` but that changed nothing

Comment: You can't.  You need to version bump the upstream version number, not just the changelog version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to upload the correct tarball under a slightly different name.  It's conventional to append something like `+ds` in this kind of case: so `foo_1.0.0.orig.tar.xz` → `foo_1.0.0+ds1.orig.tar.xz` (and bump your changelog version from `1.0.0-1` to `1.0.0+ds1-1`, etc.).  If you do it with this scheme then you should be able to drop the `+ds` suffix at the next upstream release.